# SQL Convert datatype of input parameter inside Function call

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have below Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ToDotNetDateTime ( @Ticks bigint )
    RETURNS datetime2
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateTime datetime2 = '00010101';
    SET @DateTime = DATEADD( DAY, @Ticks / 864000000000, @DateTime );
    SET @DateTime = DATEADD( SECOND, ( @Ticks % 864000000000) / 10000000, @DateTime );
    RETURN DATEADD( NANOSECOND, ( @Ticks % 10000000 ) * 100, @DateTime );
END
```

When I try cast nvarchar to bigint when calling this function it gives me error:

```
select dbo.ToDotNetDateTime(CAST(UTC_Time AS BIGINT)) FROM OtoSuite_Master_Reply
```

Error says: **Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint**

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with the function and more to do with the expression `CAST(UTC_Time AS BIGINT)`. Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. Sounds like the *real* problem, however, is you are storing date and time or numerical data, as an `nvarchar`; [`nvarchar` is not a "one size fits all" data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/). Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: @Larnu, you are right. nvarchar was not in a format to get converted to bigint. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no type conversions from strings to `bigint` in the function itself.  That suggests that the issue is the calling function `CAST(UTC_Time AS BIGINT)`.

You can find the problem values using:

```
select UTC_Time
from OtoSuite_Master_Reply
where try_CAST(UTC_Time AS BIGINT) is null and UTC_Time is not null;
```

To fix the problem, you can just use `TRY_CAST()`, but you should find the offending values and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check first is UTC_Time a valid numeric value to be converted. You can use below query which will first check whether UTC_Time column is numeric.

```
select dbo.ToDotNetDateTime(CAST(UTC_Time AS BIGINT)) FROM OtoSuite_Master_Reply
ISNUMERIC(UTC_Time ) = 1
```

But this query will ignore the values for which `ISNUMERIC(UTC_Time ) = 1` is false.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is unlikely the help here. It returns plenty of false positives and false negatives as well. `ISNUMERIC('1.0')` returns `1`, for example, but `CONVERT(int,'1.0')` will error.